# How to turn on and off mfc gui by other class?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

i need to make a class that have a pointer to mfc class and to turn on and off the gui and also to have the option to take data from the gui.
thank you.

Comment: care to type some more than your so descriptive 2 lines ? To turn on / off the GUI means what exactly ?

Comment: Just pop up a message box asking the user to press the power button.

Comment: This question makes little or no sense.  Please rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "turn on and off the GUI" I will assume you mean hide or display the main window, since you haven't provided a good description of what you're looking for. You can use [CWnd::ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72szh9c7(v=vs.80).aspx) with a parameter of `SW_HIDE` to turn the window off, and use `SW_SHOW` or `SW_RESTORE` to show it again.

By "option to take data from the GUI" I will assume you want to do Copy and Paste from the GUI to another application. That's a much larger subject. Here's some sample code:

```
OpenClipboard();
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, dataHandle);
CloseClipboard();
```

You can find a lot more information in Microsoft's guide to [Using the Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649016(VS.85).aspx).